# How to return to the `re>` prompt to start testing a new pattern when using `pcre2test`?

Tags: pcre

```
$ ./pcre2test
PCRE2 version 10.32 2018-09-10
  re> /this bar/
data> this bar 
 0: this bar
```

When trying to hit ^D or ^C, it just simply exits or when trying different strings, that usually work on other REPLs, get simply interpreted as string literals. (Which makes sense, given the purpose of the library.)

Answer (score 1):

From the [`pcre2test` documentation](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2test.html):

> An empty line or the end of the file signals the end of the subject
>   lines for a test, at which point a new pattern or command line is
>   expected if there is still input to be read.

That is, simply press enter on the `data>` prompt.